# Как разхешировать пароль?

Tags: python, django, password-hash

Доброе время суток! Есть вот такая библиотека

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
```

И вот такой способ хеширования

```
enc_password = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(password)
```

Перекопал весь интернет и не смог найти, как мне вернуть пароль в исходное состояние, допустим, для вывода на странице?

Comment: Хеширование — это операция с потерей данных, поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос — никак. На самом деле иначе не было бы никакого смысла в хранении хэша пароля вместо него самого.

Comment: никак!))) работает в одну сторону!  ребята выше норм описали

Comment: В интернете есть словари, в которых прописано соответствие "хеш" - "пароль" с достаточно объемными базами. Сложные пароли там вряд ли есть, но вот хеши типа `qwerty` или `admin12345` там точно есть.

Comment: @Bogdan да ну, и даже для pbkdf2 словари есть?

Answer (score 1):

Брутфорс либо поиск по радужным таблицам, но зачем ?)

Comment: В тестовом задании есть пункты: Показать\скрыть пароль по кнопке. А в более сложном уровне: Хеширование пароля. Вот и подумал, что могу на два стула сесть, удивить проверяющего

Comment: @NikitaTarasov обычно кнопку «Показать\скрыть пароль» делают в форме регистрации возле поля ввода пароля (в браузере, ещё до хеширования) просто для удобства пользователя, чтобы он проверил введённый пароль на наличие/отсутствие опечаток